# Conditional Formatting and text: Based on a condition I want to copy the format of another cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

In excel

I am trying to copy the elements and cell format of another cell based on some condition.

G12 = (If C10 = C11, *Leave Blank, If (C10>C11, *Copy the elements and format of B10, *Copy the elements and format of B11))

I've tried this function and have had success with copying the elements, but cannot get the formatting to change as well. I used:

=IF($C$10=$C$11,"",IF($C$10>$C$11,B10,B11))

I learned about conditional formatting but don't see a way to copy the format of another cell based on some condtion. The color has to be specified.

Thanks for the help!

tl:dr

[March Madness Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95g1X.jpg)

Virginia beat UNC 76 to 75

I want to copy Copy (1) Virginia to the next spot in the bracket with the lime green background. Had UNC won, I would want (16) UNC and the rose color to copy into the next bracket spot

Answer (score 0):

Go to vb-editor (Alt + F11), insert new module and paste this code:

```
Function RangeSelectionPrompt(txt As String) As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(txt, "Select a range", Type:=8)

    Set RangeSelectionPrompt = rng
End Function

Sub FormatAs()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim txt1 As String, txt2 As String
    Dim cel As Range, Col As Range
    Dim Val, check As Long, pos As Long

    Set Sh = ActiveSheet

    txt1 = "Enter Range #1 - sourse"
    txt2 = "Enter Range #2 - to paste formats"

    Set r1 = Intersect(RangeSelectionPrompt(txt1), Sh.UsedRange)
    Set r2 = Intersect(RangeSelectionPrompt(txt1), Sh.UsedRange)


    For Each cel In r2.Cells

        Val = cel.Value

        If Val <> "" Then

            For Each Col In r1.Columns

                check = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Col, Val)

                If check > 0 Then
                    pos = WorksheetFunction.Match(Val, Col, 0)

                    Col.Cells(pos, 1).Copy
                    cel.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

                End If

            Next Col

        End If

    Next cel

End Sub
```

Run it once to copy formats. You'll need to define two ranges:
[image]

Source range (A:B) and range to paste (F:G)

Comment: Max,

Thanks for the response. It doesn't look like this is exactly the functionality I'm looking for unfortunately. I've been in touch with Microsoft support and it seems that the kind of function I am looking for is impossible. Basically, I was looking for a conditional function that would copy values (text) as well as format (fill colors and borders).